# How do I use spring-security with struts 1.2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, struts-1

I am working from this example:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-xml-example/

But I have no idea how to configure spring security to redirect to struts when it is finished.